# List view web part to display all item from document folder in subsites (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, content-query-web-part, list-view-web-part

How can I achieve that I can display all the documents from the document libraries from all the site collections sub sites? (Actually I only need to show the onces that where changed lately.)

It seems to me that List View and Content Query web parts can't handle this. The List View web part only takes one spezific list and the Content Query also shows all the css from style library (which is a document library as well).

Or is it possible to use a custom XSLT with the Content Query web part, so I can filter them myself? But then, how can I access all the fields from the documents to have the web part look like a List View?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Tom,

For cross-site queries you can use [SiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)

Then you can use [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx) to show results, here are [some samples on using SPGridView](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16)...

OOB AFAIK is not available what you trying to achieve, but when it comes to code - you CAN!